# How do I paginate code that I receive from a function?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, datatables

I have the function "result" where I get the data for each page to be shown, but I am unsure how to send all this data to HTML and have a page link format at the bottom of the table in HTML directing it to other parts of the data. I can't call all the data at once so it has to be on-demand. Any suggestions on how I should proceed?

I have tried looking to pagination, but it only directs me to pagination with SQL alchemy or just to the point of creating the result function, but no connection with HTML.

I have listed below most of my code, skipped some JS related to some buttons

Flask:

```
import flask
from flask import request,render_template,jsonify,Blueprint
from flask.helpers import url_for
from flask.wrappers import Request
import jinja2
import pymssql
import pandas as pd
from flask_paginate import Pagination, get_page_parameter
from app2 import get_main_task, get_project_details, get_sub_task,get_proj_details

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
# print(proj) 
conn = pymssql.connect("10.20.4.44", "CSMSPMT_usr", "CSMSPMT_usr", "CSMSUAT")
query = f"SELECT Project_Id FROM VW_CSMS_PMT_ProjectDetails"
x = pd.read_sql(query,con=conn)['Project_Id'].tolist()

@app.route('/')
def lhome():
    
    return render_template('newHome.html')

print(len(x))
@app.route('/result', methods=['GET'])
def result():

    offset = int(request.args['offset'])

    limit = int(request.args['limit'])
    if(offset+limit >=len(x)):
        print(x[offset:])
        details = get_project_details(x[offset:],conn)
    else:
        print('b')
        details = get_project_details(x[offset:offset+limit],conn)
    if(offset +limit <len(x)):
        next_url = '/result?limit='+ str(limit)+ '&offset='+str(offset+limit)
    else:
        next_url = ''
    prev_url = '/result?limit='+ str(limit)+ '&offset='+str(offset-limit)
    return (render_template('',jsonify({'result':details,'next_url':next_url,'prev_url':prev_url})))

#pagination

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML:

```
   <head>
        <title>Project Details</title>
    </head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
    <script rc="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.0/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.0/css/dataTables.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>    <script></script>
    <body> 
        <table id='my-table' class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
            <thead>
                <tr>            
                    <th>Project</th>
                    <th>Main Task</th>
                    <th>Sub Task</th>
                    <th>Start Date</th>
                    <th>Target Date</th>
                    <th>Actual Start Date</th>
                    <th>Actual Target Date</th>
                    <th>Estimate</th>
                    <th>Actual Hours Hours</th>
                    <th>Approved Hours</th>
                    <th>Overall Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {%- for val in details -%}
                <tr>
                    {%- set count = loop.index -1 -%}
                    <td><button id='{{count}}' onclick="myFunction(this)">Expand</button>{{val['name']}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>{{val['start_date']}}</td>
                    <td>{{val['target_date']}}</td>
                    <td>{{val['timesheet_details']['actual_start_date']}}</td>
                    <td>{{val['timesheet_details']['actual_target_date']}}</td>
                    <td>{{val['estimate']}}</td>
                    <td>{{val['timesheet_details']['actual_hours']}}</td>
                    <td>{{val['timesheet_details']['approved_hours']}}</td>
                    <td>{{val['status']}}</td>
                </tr>
            {%- endfor -%}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('#my-table').DataTable( {
    responsive: true,
    pagingType: "simple",
    pageLength: 2,
} 
);
}
```

Comment: You are using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) already. Normally, DataTables expects all the data to be passed to it up-front, and then it handles all pagination client-side. In your case, if you need to pass one page at a time, then you can use [`serverSide: true`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide), and also implement the necessary client-server [data structures](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) used by DataTables. All paging, sorting and filtering logic is implemented in Flask, in that case.

Comment: You can see more background [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67957346/datatables-js-how-to-use-ajax-option-with-a-callback-function/67959632#67959632).

Comment: @andrewjames How do I render the page, becasue currently I send in the details as a variable in Jinja and access it, but I am unsure how to even render the data.

Comment: There are various ways to pass data to a DataTable and have it be rendered. The most common (but not the only) way for server-side processing is via JSON and Ajax.  That is what I meant by "_Your table will typically have a simple ajax section..._" in the link in my second comment. It's a very different approach from your current approach. You still have your Jinja templates, but they are much simpler (no need for all those table expressions) - and table data is JSON, provided via Ajax.

Comment: @andrewjames I am trying to set up the data table. and I can't seem to send the data properly, as in that the next button isn't active, I don't understand how to get the data of where the function call starts and stops, I am looking at the datatables.net website and can't find too much info on it there either, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "how to get the data of where the function call starts and stops" - but if you mean how to access the paging information, then that is a Flask task not a DataTables task. DataTables provides the `start` and `length` values as documented in the above "data structures" link. Your Flask app retrieves that data from the Ajax request (typically a POST request) and builds its response accordingly.

Comment: But the ```start``` and  ```length```  values aren't going through the URL so I am not sure how to access the values @andrewjames

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "aren't going through the URL". What URL are you referring to? These parameters are in the _request_ sent from DataTables to your Flask server. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67957346/datatables-js-how-to-use-ajax-option-with-a-callback-function/67959632#67959632), this request is "generated automatically by DataTables", and assumes your DataTable "will typically have a simple ajax section". In my example it's a POST request, so these values are in the request body - not part of the URL.

Comment: I don't know how familiar you are with Ajax, or with POST/GET requests and responses. But these are fundamental to how this solution works. Flask can read the request _body_ to get data from a POST request; and it can read the URL request _parameters_ to get that same data from a GET request. I recommend POST, here. I can't really provide a tutorial about these things in a SO question, if that is where the problem lies - sorry. Otherwise, I am not sure where the mis-communication is happening.