# How to update the content from table using backend and pagenumber

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, asp.net-core-webapi, datatables-1.10

Goal:
Use page number in order to retrieve fresh data from backend and then display it at frontend..

Problem:
I was enable to retrieve data from backend with pagenumber as a parameter but it doesn't show it in the list. What part of the code, front end code, am I missing?

Jsbin:
https://jsbin.com/yaroliqoyu/edit?js,console,output

Info:
*Primary use client mode if possible.
*Using .net core webapi (framework 5 for .net core) as a backend
*The backend is a simplified sample.
*Using Datatable for frontend with jquery.
*The total row is less than 50 000 row and the total row is about 30 000 row.
*In order to improve the performance I need to get the list of data based on based pagenumber and not total row.

Thank you!

---

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc; 
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging; 
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using RestSharp; 
using RestSharp.Authenticators; 
using Newtonsoft.Json; 


namespace CloudTableApi.Controllers 

{ 
    [ApiController] 
    [Route("api/[controller]")] 
    public class TestsController : ControllerBase 
    { 
        /// <summary> 
        /// https://localhost:44340/api/Tests/ 
        /// </summary> 
        /// <returns></returns> 
        [HttpGet("GetAllPosts")] 
        public Info GetAllPosts() 
        { 
            var client = new RestClient("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"); 
            var request = new RestRequest("comments", DataFormat.Json); 
            var response = client.Get(request); 

            List<Comment> m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Comment>>(response.Content); 

            Info my = new Info(); 
            my.Data = m; 

            return my; 
        } 

 
        /// <summary> 
        /// https://localhost:44340/api/Tests/SimpleGetAllPostsByPagenumber?pagenumber=1 
        /// </summary> 
        /// <param name="pagenumber"></param> 
        /// <returns></returns> 
        [HttpGet("SimpleGetAllPostsByPagenumber")] 
        public List<Comment> SimpleGetAllPostsByPagenumber(int pagenumber) 
        { 
           var clientAllData = new RestClient("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"); 
            var requestAllData = new RestRequest("comments", DataFormat.Json); 
            var responseAllData = clientAllData.Get(requestAllData); 

            List<Comment> datawithpagenumberAllData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Comment>>(responseAllData.Content); 

 
            //---------- 

            var client = new RestClient("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"); 
            var request = new RestRequest("comments?postId=" + pagenumber.ToString(), DataFormat.Json); 
            var response = client.Get(request); 
            List<Comment> datawithpagenumber = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Comment>>(response.Content); 

            //---------- 

 

            /* 

            Info info = new Info(); 

            info.Data = datawithpagenumber; 

            info.TotalRecords = datawithpagenumberAllData.Count(); 

            info.TotalDisplayRecords = datawithpagenumber.Count(); 

            */ 


            return datawithpagenumber; 
        } 

 
        /// <summary> 
        /// https://localhost:44340/api/Tests/GetAllPostsByPagenumber?pagenumber=1 
        /// </summary> 
        /// <param name="pagenumber"></param> 
        /// <returns></returns> 
        [HttpGet("GetAllPostsByPagenumber")] 
        public Info GetAllPostsByPagenumber(int pagenumber) 
        { 
            var clientAllData = new RestClient("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"); 
            var requestAllData = new RestRequest("comments", DataFormat.Json); 
            var responseAllData = clientAllData.Get(requestAllData); 

            List<Comment> datawithpagenumberAllData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Comment>>(responseAllData.Content); 

 

            //---------- 

            var client = new RestClient("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"); 
            var request = new RestRequest("comments?postId=" + pagenumber.ToString(), DataFormat.Json); 
            var response = client.Get(request); 

            List<Comment> datawithpagenumber = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Comment>>(response.Content); 

            //---------- 

            Info info = new Info(); 
            info.Data = datawithpagenumber; 
            info.TotalRecords = datawithpagenumberAllData.Count(); 
            info.TotalDisplayRecords = datawithpagenumber.Count(); 

            return info; 
        } 

         

 

    } 

 
    public class Info 
    { 
        public int TotalRecords { get; set; } 
        public int TotalDisplayRecords { get; set; } 
        public List<Comment> Data { get; set; } 
    } 

 
    public class Comment 
    { 
        public int PostId { get; set; } 
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public string Email { get; set; } 
        public string Body { get; set; } 
    } 

}
```

---

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder; 

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting; 

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy; 

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc; 

using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration; 

using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; 

using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting; 

using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging; 

using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models; 

using System; 

using System.Collections.Generic; 

using System.Linq; 

using System.Threading.Tasks; 

 

namespace CloudTableApi 

{ 

    public class Startup 

    { 

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) 

        { 

            Configuration = configuration; 

        } 

 

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; } 

 

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container. 

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 

        { 

 

            services.AddCors(options => 

            { 

                options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", 

                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()); 

            }); 

 

            services.AddControllers(); 

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c => 

            { 

                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "CloudTableApi", Version = "v1" }); 

            }); 

        } 

 

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline. 

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) 

        { 

            app.UseCors(builder => builder 

                .AllowAnyOrigin() 

                .AllowAnyMethod() 

                .AllowAnyHeader()); 

 

 

            if (env.IsDevelopment()) 

            { 

                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); 

                app.UseSwagger(); 

                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "CloudTableApi v1")); 

            } 

 

            app.UseHttpsRedirection(); 

 

            app.UseRouting(); 

 

            app.UseAuthorization(); 

 

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => 

            { 

                endpoints.MapControllers(); 

            }); 

        } 

    } 

}
```

---

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
getDataFirstTime(1);
  
});



function getDataFirstTime(ab)
{
  
$('#example').DataTable( {
    
  "processing": true, 
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax":{
    url:"https://localhost:44340/api/Tests/SimpleGetAllPostsByPagenumber?pagenumber=" + ab,
 //     url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=" + pagenumber,       
    dataSrc: ""
  },
  "columns": [
    { data: "postId" },
    { data: "id" },
    { data: "name" },
    { data: "email" },
    { data: "body" }
  ]
});  
    
  
}



$('#example').on( 'draw.dt', function () {
  
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  
  var number = table.page();

  var a = parseInt(number);
  
  
  $.getJSON("https://localhost:44340/api/Tests/SimpleGetAllPostsByPagenumber?pagenumber=" + a, function(result)
  {
    console.log("Page numberr: " + a);
    console.log("Page numberrr: " + number);

    updateTable(a + 1, result);
  });  
  
  
});


function updateTable(number, jsonData)
{
    var transactionsTable = $('#example');  
  
    console.log("Page number: " + number);
    console.log(jsonData);

  
    transactionsTable.DataTable( {
    "retrieve": true,
    "paging": true,
      "ajax":{
        url:"https://localhost:44340/api/Tests/SimpleGetAllPostsByPagenumber?pagenumber=" + number,
 //     url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=" + pagenumber,       
        dataSrc: ""
      },
      data: jsonData,
      "columns": [
        { data: "postId" },
        { data: "id" },
        { data: "name" },
        { data: "email" },
        { data: "body" }
      ]
    });
}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>PostId</th>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Body</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>


  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: DataTables already handles this for you _automatically_ when you use `serverSide=true`. See the [Sent Parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) section of the documentation. Specifically, see the `start` and `length` parameters. These tell you which record to start at, and how many records there are in a page, when building the response. That is all you need to return the correct page of data in your response.

Comment: Your responsibility is to ensure your response not only includes the data but also [these extra attributes](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) in the response. (Bottom line: I am not really sure why you are trying to do what you are trying to do, when there is an official way of doing this, already provided by DataTables.)

Comment: DO you need to apply start and length parameter as a parameter variable in the backend? Do you have a sample?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. You can get "page number" from "start" and "length" with a simple piece of arithmetic, if you really need to. If you know there are 10 records per page, then you can calculate the page number for record 1,234 (remembering that record numbers start at zero). You can see an overview of server-side processing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67957346/datatables-js-how-to-use-ajax-option-with-a-callback-function/67959632#67959632). Those notes also point you to a full end-to-end example (it's PHP - but that is not relevant to the concepts involved).