# Datatables.net - Server Side processing with DRF - Can't navigate

Tags: python, vue.js, django-rest-framework, datatables

I have thousands of records coming from the DRF API so i'm trying to use Datatables server-side processing.

I'm having errors which i don't clearly understand.

The data i'm receiving from the API is the following:

```
{
    "count": 4893,
    "next": "http://localhost/api/forecasts/demand/files/?_=1632316747353&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=1&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=2&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=3&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=4&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=5&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=6&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&draw=3&length=10&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&page=2&search%5Bregex%5D=false&search%5Bvalue%5D=&start=20",
    "previous": null,
    "recordsTotal": 4893,
    "recordsFiltered": 4893,
    "data": [
        {
            "data_chamada": "2021-06-23T15:00:01+01:00",
            "data_previsao": "2021-06-26T01:00:00+01:00",
            "data_lancamento": "2021-06-23T16:21:20+01:00",
            "ficheiro": "PREVISAO_D3_2021_06_23_1521.xlsx",
            "t_comp": 2168.05771255493,
            "n_pontos": "1318/1415"
        },        
        {
            "data_chamada": "2021-05-31T15:00:01+01:00",
            "data_previsao": "2021-06-02T01:00:00+01:00",
            "data_lancamento": "2021-05-31T15:39:27+01:00",
            "ficheiro": "PREVISAO_D2_2021_05_31_1439.xlsx",
            "t_comp": 2430.79512739182,
            "n_pontos": "1292/1418"
        },
    ...
     
    ]
}
```

My code on the frontend is something like this:

```
<template>
  <section id="forecast_table">
    <table id="example" class="uk-table uk-table-hover uk-table-striped"
           style="width:100%; border: 1px #F0F0F0 solid; font-size: 12px;">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="color:black; "><small>data chamada</small></th>
        <th style="color:black; "><small>data previsão</small></th>
        <th style="color:black; font-weight: normal;"><small>data previsao</small></th>
        <th style="color:black; font-weight: normal;"><small>ficheiro</small></th>
        <th style="color:black; font-weight: normal;"><small>tempo (s)</small></th>
        <th style="color:black; font-weight: normal;"><small>pontos</small></th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    data() {
      return {}
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
      paging: true,
      language: {
        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Portuguese.json",
      },
      length: 15,
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: {
        url: 'http://localhost/api/forecasts/demand/files/',
        dataFilter: function (data) {
          var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          json.recordsTotal = json.count;
          json.recordsFiltered = json.count;
          json.data = json.results;
          console.log(json)
          return JSON.stringify(json); // return JSON string
        }
      },
      columns: [
        {data: "data_chamada"},
        {data: "data_lancamento"},
        {data: "data_previsao"},
        {data: "ficheiro"},
        {data: "t_comp"},
        {data: "n_pontos"}
      ]
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

What i want to achieve is a table with the data fetched from the API where i have a paginator working with the `next`, `previous` and `numbers` from the datatables plugin.

The table is displayed with the first data request correctly inserted in the table and with the numeration correct but i can't navigate through pagination.

I see that the request by clicking in the any pagination action is fairly complex (not sure if DRF is able to understand this request). Here is a request decoded:

```
  http://localhost/api/forecasts/demand/files/?_=1632334407343&columns[0][data]=data_chamada&columns[0][name]=&columns[0][orderable]=true&columns[0][search][regex]=false&columns[0][search][value]=&columns[0][searchable]=true&columns[1][data]=data_lancamento&columns[1][name]=&columns[1][orderable]=true&columns[1][search][regex]=false&columns[1][search][value]=&columns[1][searchable]=true&columns[2][data]=data_previsao&columns[2][name]=&columns[2][orderable]=true&columns[2][search][regex]=false&columns[2][search][value]=&columns[2][searchable]=true&columns[3][data]=ficheiro&columns[3][name]=&columns[3][orderable]=true&columns[3][search][regex]=false&columns[3][search][value]=&columns[3][searchable]=true&columns[4][data]=t_comp&columns[4][name]=&columns[4][orderable]=true&columns[4][search][regex]=false&columns[4][search][value]=&columns[4][searchable]=true&columns[5][data]=n_pontos&columns[5][name]=&columns[5][orderable]=true&columns[5][search][regex]=false&columns[5][search][value]=&columns[5][searchable]=true&draw=2&length=10&order[0][column]=0&order[0][dir]=asc&page=2&search[regex]=false&search[value]=&start=10
```

Comment: Not an answer (there may be more issues hiding behind this issue). Your source JSON data contains fields such as `data_chamada`. Your DataTable does not map these JSON fields to its table columns. I would expect to see a `columns` option in your DataTable, similar to the one shown in [this AJAX-sourced data example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html).

Comment: @andrewjames thanks it helped, the data appears in the table now but the pagination is still not working. Not sure what i have to add to DataTable object...

Comment: Uodated the issue with doubts of how to setup properly the numeration.

Comment: The standard way to use pagination (and filtering and sorting) with server-side processing is for your server-side code to use the `start` and `length` [sent parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) which are automatically sent to the server by DataTables. You can read some more background notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67959632/12567365).